# How to remove white spaces after "(" in string?

Tags: lua

A lua newbie here.

I would like to replace the string `'$\\psi\\left(  y\\right)$'`  with `'$\\psi\\left(y\\right)$'`  i.e. remove any white spaces that show up after `(` and before the next non-white space character.

I have been trying `gsub` but each attempt did not work.  This is what I tried

```
function foo(s)
print('before s = '..s)
str=string.gsub(s,"\\left(  ","\\left(")
print('after s= '..str)
return str
end
```

And tried

```
function foo(s)
print('before s = '..s)
str=string.gsub(s,"\\left(%s+","\\left(")
print('after s= '..str)
return str
end
```

And few other variations. But each time I call the function as follows

```
 foo('$\\psi\\left(  y\\right)$')
```

The string returned is the same. The white space is still there.

What is the correct way to do this?  Using Lua `5.2.4` on linux.

I intend to use this function inside lualatex, and these strings will be passed from latex to lua as strings.  But I am now trying this function in standalone lua installation on Linux first to see if it works before I use it inside Lualatex.

Comment: u can try with regex it should be easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magic characters like `(` need to be escaped.

Please refer to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1

Replace `"\\left(%s+"` with `"\\left%(%s+"` or `"\\left(  +"` with `"\\left%(  +"`

Looks to me like some bug. This should actually result in an "unfinished capture" error. At least it would if `(` was the first character in the pattern.